# Measuring of Bezier surface curvature at point

Tags: curvature

For the first time I will ask the theoretical question here. Еell me, please, is there an optimized formula for calculating the principal curvatures of the Bezier surface at a given point? Now I'm trying to implement the common formula K = H +- Sqrt[H^2-G], but... The surface is of the 6th degree and the resulting formula takes about 1,000,000 symbols (but to tell the truth, it gets the right result). I honestly searched for data on the web, but found nothing...

So, how did I try to solve this problem.

Let the surface of the 5th degree (5 by 5) be given as an array of control vertices, in other words, three arrays for each coordinate Ax,Ay,Az.Then, the parametric equation describing the surface A is

```
P1 = {(1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
   1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 2, 
   1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
   1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
   1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 1] + 
  u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 1] + 
  v (-5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 1]) + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 2])) + 
  v^2 (10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 1]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 2]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 3])) + 
  v^3 (-10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1,
          1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 1]) + 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 2]) - 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 3]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 4])) + 
  v^4 (5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 1]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 2]) + 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 3]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 4]) + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         5] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 5] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         5] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         5] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 5] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 5])) + 
  v^5 (-((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
        1]) + (1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
      1, 6] - (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
      2, 1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
      2, 6] - (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
      1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
      6] - (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
      1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
      6] - (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 
      1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 6] - 
     u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 1] + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 2]) - 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 3]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 4]) - 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ax, 1, 
         5] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 
         2, 5] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 3, 
         5] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 4, 
         5] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ax, 5, 5] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 5]) + u^5 Subscript[Ax, 6, 6]), (1 - 
     5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
   1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 2, 
   1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
   1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
   1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 1] + 
  u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 1] + 
  v (-5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 1]) + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 2])) + 
  v^2 (10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 1]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 2]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 3])) + 
  v^3 (-10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1,
          1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 1]) + 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 2]) - 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 3]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 4])) + 
  v^4 (5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 1]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 2]) + 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 3]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 4]) + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         5] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 5] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         5] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         5] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 5] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 5])) + 
  v^5 (-((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
        1]) + (1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
      1, 6] - (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
      2, 1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
      2, 6] - (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
      1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
      6] - (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
      1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
      6] - (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 
      1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 6] - 
     u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 1] + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 2]) - 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 3]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 4]) - 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Ay, 1, 
         5] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 
         2, 5] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 3, 
         5] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 4, 
         5] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Ay, 5, 5] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 5]) + u^5 Subscript[Ay, 6, 6]), (1 - 
     5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
   1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 2, 
   1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
   1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
   1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 1] + 
  u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 1] + 
  v (-5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 1]) + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 2])) + 
  v^2 (10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 1]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 2]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 3])) + 
  v^3 (-10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1,
          1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 1]) + 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 2]) - 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 3]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 4])) + 
  v^4 (5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 1] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 1]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 2]) + 
     30 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 3]) - 
     20 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 4]) + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         5] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 5] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         5] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         5] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 5] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 5])) + 
  v^5 (-((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
        1]) + (1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 
      1, 6] - (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
      2, 1] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
      2, 6] - (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
      1] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
      6] - (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
      1] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
      6] - (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 
      1] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 6] - 
     u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 1] + 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         2] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 2] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         2] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         2] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 2] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 2]) - 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         3] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 3] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         3] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         3] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 3] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 3]) + 
     10 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         4] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 4] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         4] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         4] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 4] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 4]) - 
     5 ((1 - 5 u + 10 u^2 - 10 u^3 + 5 u^4 - u^5) Subscript[Az, 1, 
         5] + (5 u - 20 u^2 + 30 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 
         2, 5] + (10 u^2 - 30 u^3 + 30 u^4 - 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 3, 
         5] + (10 u^3 - 20 u^4 + 10 u^5) Subscript[Az, 4, 
         5] + (5 u^4 - 5 u^5) Subscript[Az, 5, 5] + 
        u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 5]) + u^5 Subscript[Az, 6, 6])}. In general, the main task is to find a point on the surface at which the major principal curvature is maximal. So, the major principal curvature Kmax = H + Sqrt[H^2 - K], where H is mean curvature, and K is Gaussian curvature. Next, the formulas become incredibly cumbersome, so I'll be asking general formulas here. So, 

NSGaussianCurvature[x_List, {u_, v_}] /; Length[x] == 3 := 
 Module[{du = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(u\)]x\), dv = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(v\)]x\)}, (Det[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(u, u\)]x\), du, dv}] Det[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(v, v\)]x\), du, dv}] - Det[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(u, v\)]x\), du, dv}]^2)/(du . 
       du dv . dv - (du . dv)^2)^2]
```

(NS means "non-simplified", because Wolfram cannot simplify it). Aswell,

```
NSMeanCurvature[x_, {u_, v_}] := Module[{du = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(u\)]x\), dv = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(v\)]x\)},
  (Det[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(u, u\)]x\), du, dv}] dv . dv - 
     2 Det[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(u, v\)]x\), du, dv}] du . dv + 
     Det[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(v, v\)]x\), du, dv}] du . 
       du)/(2 (du . du dv . dv - (du . dv)^2)^(3/2))]
```

.

> H = NSMeanCurvature[P1, {u, v}]

,

> K = NSGaussianCurvature[P1, {u, v}]

. So, `Kmax = H + Sqrt[H^2 - K]`. That's it...

Comment: This is one of the reasons why using Bezier surfaces is not as a good idea as it seems first...

Comment: What could be an alternative?

Comment: Please post an example of Bezier surface and the relate curvature formula by Mathematica code.

Comment: I wanted to specify the coordinates of the control vertices, but I didn't have enough characters in the post...

Comment: And a little addition: Rhinoceros 3D calculates the principal curvatures at point instantly, I mean when I tried to calculate 10,000 curvature values (one hundred dots on each side), the calculation time was about 0.1 sec at all...

Comment: First you asked about a symbolica formula. Now you seem to be interested in performance. These two goals are often quite orthogonal to each other.